# Android spinner location not updating

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner that populated with a string array. The spinner is populated when a button is pressed. the output is always game_0 even if I use the spinner and select say game_3. Is this because it's in a function?

```
    public void game(View view) throws IOException {    
    myText="";
    TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String game_list[] = {"game_0","game_2","game_3","game_3","game_4","game_5"};
    for(int i=0; i<game_list.length; i++){
    myText = myText + game_list[i] +"\n";
    }
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, game_list); 
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    myTextView.setText("");
    myTextView.append(text);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you calling your `game(View v)` method? There's no space for user action between the spinner initialization `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` and the line that extract the selected value which is obviously (by default) the first of the array..."game_0".

You can use an OnItemSelectedListener to listen for user action on the spinner, or use a button with a click listener to check the spinner value upon submit.

Here's an example of a selected listener applied to a spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            // here get the selected value and do whatever you want
    }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // ignore this if you're not going to provide a "no-selection" option
        }
    });
```